# openLayers map is undefined error

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

When I add `var view` after `map.on("singleclick", function(event)` I notice that the method `getView()` ( http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#getView ) stops working. Can anybody give me a hint why that happens? In my browsers console I get the following error:

TypeError: map is undefined

Here is my code:

```
map.on("singleclick", function(event) {
var map = evt.map;
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature
    }
)
var icon_feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(event.coordinate),
        type: 'icon',
        coords: event.coordinate
    })
    icon_feature.setStyle(icon_style)
    icon_layer.getSource().addFeature(icon_feature)
})

var view = map.getView(); //error in this line
//more code here ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't redefine your `map` (`var map = evt.map;`) variable! Just use:

```
var view = map.getView();
```